# Word describing the relationship between a worker and a task

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Owner -> property: ownership

Worker -> task: ?

The first "*ship" word that came to my mind was "workmanship" but that word clearly does not fit.

EDIT:

Both "**employment**" (the accepted answer) and "**assignment**" (as raised in the comments) should be able to describe the worker-task relationship.

Thanks!

Comment: ***Assignment***.

Comment: @DanBron Hmmmm, that works! But is there any "*ship" word for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds odd nowadays because it brings to mind human resources departments, but I have heard "employment" in exactly that context. "No, I will clear up after lunch: I must have some employment this afternoon."

Comment: I found [*The real relation of the employee to the company might be called “**workership**.”*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22workership%22) But *work, worker, workership* doesn't really do it for me. *Employ, employee, employment* is probably best, even if it essentially revolves around what the *employer* does, rather than what the worker himself does (or what attribute he acquires by doing it).